# Oracle GoldenGate vs VMWare Continuent Tungsten

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate, tungsten-replicator

We are looking Some real time replication from Oracle database to Big Data (Cassandra). Oracle GoldenGate is very good for this but licensing cost is huge. We also looking for VMWare Continuent Tungsten. Can anybody tell shortcomings of using VMWare Continuent Tungsten over GoldenGate?

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS is an asynchronous database replication software package that supports multiple subscribers and bi-directional synchronization. It uses web and database technologies to replicate tables between relational databases in near real time. The software was designed to scale for a large number of databases, work across low-bandwidth connections, and withstand periods of network outage. It includes support for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, H2, HSQLDB, Derby, MS SQL Server, Firebird, IBM DB2, Informix, Interbase, and Greenplum databases

https://www.itcentralstation.com/categories/other-data-integration-and-access-tools#top_rated

Answer (score 0):

It may be a perception that GoldenGate is expensive. However, the total cost of ownership (TCO) for Oracle GoldenGate to deliver to Big Data systems is much lower since GoldenGate licensing to Big Data is not based on the number of target systems. Also with GoldenGate for Big Data you could also get a promotional SKU of Oracle Stream Analytics for doing stream data processing (or Stream ETL) as well. So the summary is that many find it really valuable to use GoldenGate as an enterprise-wide big data and cloud integration tool than using a lot of point solutions which could be potential SPOF.

Comment: GoldenGate for Big Data along with Oracle Stream Analytics is available on cloud for less than a dollar per hour per OCPU. Refer: https://cloudmarketplace.oracle.com/marketplace/en_US/listing/77101067